# Gitlab Docker login on wrong registry

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I configured a docker runner for gitlab which works fine and the default container is the docker:stable container. In Gitlab I try to use that container for a CI job which looks the following.

```
variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - docker build --cache-from=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
  tags:
    - docker
```

There is an error which states:

$ docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/auth: dial tcp: lookup docker on 192.168.24.10:53: server misbehaving

It seems that the CI_REGISTRY variable is not set properly because I have a private registry running on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I was not using my own gitlab running. After a lot of reading, I found out that the runner needs to run with the `--privileged=true` option. Then finally I realized that the "Group Runners" have not set that flag. The issue got fixed by disabling the "Group Runners" in the ci/cd settings in gitlab, and just enabling the "Shared Runners". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the variable is not protected or masked in GitLab settings.

Comment: No it is not protected or masked and I tried to set the variable inside the variables menu but still the same error.

Comment: Try echoing  the variables in your script to try to isolate the problem